# How can I create a new keyboard layout for KDE 4?

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout

I would like to define a new keyboard layout for KDE 4. In particular I would like to take the standard British layout and add Polish characters for the combinations Alt-Gr + letter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KDE simply uses the X server's keyboard mapping facility (XKB). This is more complex than it looks, and definitely more complex than it *should* be. *Sigh.*

The quick and dirty answer would be to combine the files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl` into a new file, but you also need to provide information via XML for front-ends (like KDE4), and you'd probably have to read a few hundred pages of documentation.

But you may be able to get away with less: have you seen [this tutorial on making a hybrid de/pl keymap](http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/~mikosmul/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html)?